# How to run SystemJS/React demo locally with JSX?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, systemjs

I'm following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NpMnRifyGyw) video tutorial at the moment and I'm stuck with the simple HelloWorld App. At the time position [12m:31s](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NpMnRifyGyw#t=12m31s) is where I'm stuck it should show `HelloWorld` but it doesn't.

The App is using SystemJs, React and JSX.

To create the app do these steps in your terminal (node and jspm required):

- `npm init` (`enter` to all)
- `jspm init` (`enter` to almost all, except use babel)
- `jspm install fetch=npm:whatwg-fetch`
- `jspm install react`
- create an app sub-folder create `main.js` and copy my code into it
- create `index.html` into root dir.
- Then run it with [serve](https://www.npmjs.com/package/serve)

I think the problem is my local server. I'm running it with nodejs `http-server` and I think the JSX is not transpiled to JS. Also the mentioned `serve` server is not working.

I'm getting this error message in the browser console:

```
Potentially unhandled rejection [3] SyntaxError: Error loading "app/main"
[...] Unexpected token <
```

How do I make it work?

Here is my code, exactly the code from the video (it doesn't run here because no js files added):

```js
//app/main.js
import 'fetch';

import React from 'react';

console.log('Hello world');

class HelloWorld extends React.Component {
 render() {
  return <p>hello world</p>;
 }
}

React.render(<HelloWorld />, document.body);
```

```html
<!-- index.html -->
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>First jspm</title>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="jspm_packages/system.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="config.js"></script>
 <script>
  System.import('app/main');
 </script>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where you say "expect use babel" -- is that supposed to be "except"? I'm not looking at the whole tutorial, just going from what's in your post, but why except babel? Is that what's supposed to be transpiling your JSX in this scenario?

Comment: Yes, sorry, it's a typo. It's except. I'll fix this in a minute. I just use Babel because it's recommended in the tutorial. Not sure what is transpiling the jsx. But Babel have a JSX transformer and maybe it is not used by my code yet.

Comment: Does "except use babel" mean that you're including or excluding babel?

Comment: Sorry, it means use babel instead of default option traceur.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i have no idea specifically about this tutorial, but JSX needs to have the JSX transpiler included before your JSX files are loaded.  it then looks for any script tags that have type="text/jsx" to compile to regular JavaScript.

It sound's like this tutorial may have complicated this matter.

Comment: Thanks for the tip that the transpiling needs to happen before the jsx files are loaded. That pushed me in the right direction. Babel will do the transpiling if correctly configured.

Answer (score 5):

get similar issue when i work on a es6+react demo on browser, figure out finally

```
<!doctype html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/systemjs/0.20.12/system.js"></script>

<script>
SystemJS.config({
    baseURL:'https://unpkg.com/',
    defaultExtension: true,
    meta: {
        '*.jsx': {
            'babelOptions': {
                react: true
            }
        }
    },
    map: {
        'plugin-babel': 'systemjs-plugin-babel@latest/plugin-babel.js',
        'systemjs-babel-build': 'systemjs-plugin-babel@latest/systemjs-babel-browser.js',
        'react': 'react@15.3.2/dist/react.min.js',
        'react-dom': 'react-dom@15.3.2/dist/react-dom.min.js'
    },
    transpiler: 'plugin-babel'
});


SystemJS.import('./comp-a.jsx').then(function (m) {
    console.log(m);
});
</script>
```

Comment: thank you very much for sharing this.  It made my day. :D

Answer (score 4):

Ok, I've figured it out.

It was mentioned in the video tutorial but I thought it is not needed. Anyway, it is required.

Add `blacklist: []` to the configuration of babelconfig inside of config.js!!

From [Babel homepage](https://babeljs.io/docs/using-babel/#jspm):

> JSX support is currently disabled by jspm. To re-enable it, add `"blacklist": []` to `babelOptions` in the jspm configuration file.

With this added Babel will automatically check the `imports / exports` and transpils the jsx.

Comment: I would add that you need new version of jspm as well! 
That was the reason why it failed with same error for me

Comment: This is not working for me, is it still a valid solution?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the current way to use jsx with jspm (with jspm 0.16.* anyway) is to install:

```
jspm install npm:jspm-loader-jsx
```

This is the only way I've managed to get it working. I didn't have to set the blacklist to []. I'm using the .js extension.

I learned about jspm-loader-jsx from [this blog post](http://egorsmirnov.me/2015/10/11/react-and-es6-part5.html) after many hours trying other things and searching the web for help.

In jspm 0.17.* (currently in beta), it seems like there may be a different way, but at least it's [actually covered in the jspm docs](http://jspm.io/0.17-beta-guide/installing-the-jsx-babel-plugin.html).